# Javascript onchange for dropdown value issue

Tags: php, javascript, html, onchange

I have 2 frames of php files, first is call topFrame and bottom is called mainFrame. In the topFrame I have a php file with a dropdown value, onchange I would want to reload this frame with another php file.

Below is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>RATEMASTER</title>

<script type="text/javascript">

function showsupli(sta)
{

alert ("sta");
if (sta == 'Yes')
{
window.open('ratesupli.php,'topFrame');
}
}

</script>

</head>
<body>
<?
echo "<form name='f1'>";

echo "<table width='730' border='0' align='center' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='1'>";
echo "  <tr>";
echo "    <td><span class='style3'>Suplimentry Invoice</span></td>";

echo "    <td>";
echo "<select name='supli' onchange=\"showsupli(this.value);\"><option value=0>No</option>";
  echo "<option value=1>Yes</option>";
echo "</select>";// Closing of list box
echo "</td>";
echo "  </tr>";

echo "</table>";

echo "</form>";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: variable 'sta' would never equals to "Yes". It's a value of option — 0 or 1, in your case. There is a little snippet according to your case:http://jsfiddle.net/T7USA/7/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your option values are `1` and `0`, but in your Javascript you look for `Yes`.

Change to:

```
if (sta == '1')
```

The selected value of a `<select>` is the selected `<option>` `value`, not the text.

You also have a syntax error, you forgot to close the quote after `ratesupli.php`, use:

```
window.open('ratesupli.php','topFrame');
```

Comment: I have changed as per your code, it is still not working. I feel the function showsupli() is not working, as the alert() is not showing up. pl help.

Answer (score 0):

html CHANGE

```
<option value='0'>No</option>
<option value='1'>Yes</option>
```

Javascript change

```
function showsupli(sta)
{

alert ("sta");
if (sta == '1')
{
window.open('ratesupli.php','topFrame');
}
}
```